# Alternatives to vimrc for Vim-LaTeX while Sourceforge is down

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-latex

Sourceforge has been down for the last few days. It seems the only way to find what to add to your vimrc to get Vim-LaTeX to work is to download the 'recommended settings' from Sourceforge. This information is not even in the manual.

Could someone tell me where else I could find what to put in my vimrc to setup Vim-LaTeX?

It would be great if you put a copy here for future reference.

Note: I already have Vim-LaTeX downloaded from a Linux repository, so I just need the `vimrc` file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help with Vim-LaTeX. However, I do develop my own LaTeX-plugin: [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), which I personally think is getting pretty good. There is also several other good ones (IMHO), e.g. [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box), [atp](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/) and [vim-latex-live-preview](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview).

Comment: Perhaps ask on [tex.se], you might find somebody there that has it at hand.

Comment: There is some information in the help (`:help recommended-settings`) and a lot in the "texrc" file included with the plugin (`vim-latex/ftplugin/latex-suite/texrc`). Are you looking for something beyond these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend. Specifically, [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BKe8ucxeeSwJ:vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in):

> Make sure that you create a few necessary settings in your `~/.vimrc`.
>
> ```
> " REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
> filetype plugin on
>
> " IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
> " can be called correctly.
> set shellslash
>
> " IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
> " search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
> " program to always generate a file-name.
> set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
>
> " OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
> filetype indent on
>
> " OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
> " 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
> " The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
> let g:tex_flavor='latex'
> ```
>
> In addition, the following settings could go in your
>   `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file:
>
> ```
> " this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
> " of indentation.
> set sw=2
> " TIP: if you write your \label's as \label{fig:something}, then if you
> " type in \ref{fig: and press <C-n> you will automatically cycle through
> " all the figure labels. Very useful!
> set iskeyword+=:
> ```

Though I must say I find nothing particularly unusual in here, except perhaps for:

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

Comment: @Emre That's the `recommended-settings` section from the help, which you should have if you have installed the plugin. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that's it! I misinterpreted the paragraph preceding it to mean that there was more on the vimrc file on Sourceforge. Thanks a lot, both the answer and the comment have been illuminating.